# Mysql Query from Text Area

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a form which I want to use to query a Mysql Table.  The text area will accept a list of barcodes.  Here is an example of the code form:

```
 <form action="getbarcodes.php" method="post" id="calculate">
     <div id="data">
       <label>Barcode:</label>
       <span class="error">*</span><input type="textarea" name="barcode" ><br />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Codes" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

I am trying to figure a way to write the getbarcodes.php script, and have been doing a fair bit or research in how to achieve this.  I have came across an example which I believe uses OOP to achieve the same result, however because I don't have details of the classes that were written, or PDO parameters etc, I can't figure the example out.  Therefore I was wondering how I could translate the example into a basic mysqli query:

```
foreach(explode("\n", Input::get('itemlist')) as $line) {
    $item = preg_split('/(?<=\d) (?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/i', $line);
    if (isset($item[1])) { 
    echo 'Looking for ' . $item[1];
    $itemObj = DB::table('items')->select('name', 'id')->where('name', '=',            trim($item[1], "\r"))->first();
    var_dump($itemObj);
}
```

}

I know how to look for a single barcode using .  The table name is Product.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT barcode, name, cost, salesprice, vatcode FROM   product where barcode = '$barcode' ");
```

So I presume that from the snippet I have provided, I would be changing 'itemlist' to 'barcode',  $item as $barcode.  So any help in translating this snippet so I can achieve the desired results using mysqli would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Do you expect multiple barcode entries in `textarea` or just 1?

Comment: thanks for your help RST, it will be multiple entries with each barcode on a new line

Answer (score 0):

You may need to manipulate `$_POST['barcode']` or `$barcodes` a little more if it is not in the right format.

```
if ( ! empty($_POST['barcode']) ) {
  $barcodes = explode("\n", $_POST['barcode'])
  foreach ( $barcodes as $barcode) {
    $result[] = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT barcode, name, cost, salesprice, vatcode FROM   product where barcode = '$barcode' ");
  }

  if (! empty($result)) var_dump($result);
  else echo "No Product(s) Found";
}
```

Comment: RST I have tried your example. I have fixed the errors but it returns an empty array.  So somewhere along the line, the query is not working?

Comment: I assumed the `query` command you provided worked correctly. You will have to test the used variables see if they contain the data you expect. You could start with `echo $barcode` as a first command in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! empty($_POST['submit']) && ! empty($_POST['barcode'])) {
  $barcodes = "'" . str_replace("\n", "','", $_POST['barcode']) . "'";
  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT barcode, name, cost, salesprice, vatcode FROM product where barcode IN  ($barcode)");
}
```

Use above code. Here I'm expecting barcodes separated by new line.